# Iterate and join char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, join

I've got two char arrays, which i'm trying to join character by character. Here's an illustrated example:

```
both[10]
   |
   |______both[0]
            |_____one[0]
            |
          both[1]
            |_____two[0]
            |
          both[2]
            |_____one[1]
            |
         ..etc..
```

I tried using two loops, but that didn't work for the second array. It's probably something simple, although I've not found the solution.

```
char one = "ji-hs";
char two = "onti";
char both[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    memcpy(&both[i], &one[i], 1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    memcpy(&both[i+1], &two[i], 1);
}
```

The two arrays joined together is supposed to read `join-this`

Comment: try uisng this 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    memcpy(&both[i], &one[i], 1);
    memcpy(&both[i], &two[i], 1);
}

Comment: `memcpy` is really overkill here.

Comment: Hint: where do you want `one[0]` to go? And `one[1]`? And `one[2]`?...

Comment: `one[0]` should go into `both[0]`, `one[1]` into `both[2]`, `one[2]` into `both[4]`, etc.

Comment: @Beta, and why is memcpy overkill? it seems like a simple approach from my point of view.

Comment: It looks like you need a [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)

Comment: The memcpy can be replaced by `both[i+1] = two[i]` etc.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, dang that's cool — i was completely unaware of such a thing. Does it require C++11 or anything special? thanks for sharing.

Comment: `boost::zip_iterator` requires Boost... but so do most large C++ projects. C++11 is 2.5 years old now, so hardly "special".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
char *one = "ji-hs";
char *two = "onti";
char both[11];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    both[i*2] = one[i];
    both[i*2+1] = two[i];
}
both[10] = 0;
```

Comment: One question, what does the `both[10] = 0` at the end do?

Comment: Just in case you want to use it as a string.  Not needed otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use `both` as a string, although the including/excluding `both[10] = 0` didn't seem to make a difference (that I could tell).

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for passing the bounds of your input strings - if `one = "ji-hs"`, it only has 6 characters (The 5 you declared, plus an `'\0'` at the end. Take a look at how c-style strings work). It doesn't make sense to try to access the 9th element, if there are only 6 elements stored in the first place. Your for loops access `one[i]` on all values of `i` ranging from 0-9 - meaning they'll access `one[9]` as well.

Try using the modulus function on a single loop to determine if it's odd or even. Modulus basically returns the remainder of division of its arguments.

As all odd indexes should have a value from `two` while all even indexes should have a value from `one`, you can use the result of the modusus operator to determine where to copy your value from. Note that integer division truncates the result (so 5 / 2 = 2)

I haven't tested this, but it shows the basic idea:

```
char one = "ji-hs";
char two = "onti";
char both[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (i % 2)
        both[i] = two[i/2];
    else
        both[i] = one[i/2];
}
```

Comment: Interesting, and nice explanation - all of which makes perfect sense. I guess it would be better to set up the final array size based on computing the sizes of one and two, although I'm not exactly familiar with determining the sizes without knowing in advance...

Comment: btw - it works, just needed to initalize `one` and `two` with `*`. thanks for the answer :)

Comment: to determine the size of a c-style string, you can iterate through it until you find a `'\0'` character (the end of the string). The number of characters you iterated through is the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work for simple reason, see your code and try to understand what you are doing, You are copying array **one** into **both** in first loop and followed by it you are copying  array **two**  into both in second loop that is why you are not getting the desired output.

You can try this way

```
int k=0,i=0,j=0,flag=1;
while(i<strlen(one) && j<strlen(two)) {
    if(flag) {
       memcpy(&both[k],&one[i],1);
       k++; i++;
       flag=0;
    }
    else   {
      memcpy(&both[k],&two[j],1);
       k++; j++;
       flag=1;
    }
}
for(;i<strlen(one);i++)
  memcpy(&both[k],&one[i],1);

for(;j<strlen(two);j++)
  memcpy(&both[k],&two[j],1);
```

Comment: I do understand it, and yes I want to copy array two into both, along with array one, but alternating positions in the both array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I assume `flag=` is a bool on/off type of thing?